# Why does my model behave strangely after binding to the bone structure?

Tags: rigging

Made a skeleton, combined all the parts of the character together. And then made a binding.

[image]

Then he tried to move his hand and eventually the hand tightens the lower part of the raincoat, hat and eye.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Should there be such a reaction? How to avoid it?

**File:** [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v74vh6iwfekmx4q/MagePlayer8.blend?dl=0).

Comment: I think your bones are too close to other parts of the mesh, so you should manually correct weights for problematic areas.

Comment: @SergeL maybe you can make it like answer + pictures and I accept it??